# Template implicit instantiation occurs before using it

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a question about instantiation of templates. I thought that the template imlicit instantiation occurs when it's required. Let's look at the followin example:

```
template<typename T>
struct Base{
    void test();
};

template <typename T> void Base<T>::test(){ }

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T>{
    void derived();
};

template <typename T> void Derived<T>::derived(){ test(); }
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c6ab39de2f8e701

This code doesn't compile. I thought the existence of `test` should be checked  only when explicitly or implicitly instantiating like in the following example:

```
template<typename T>
struct Derived{
    void derived();
};

template <typename T> void Derived<T>::derived(){ T::test(); }  //fine
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a template is first parsed, all names in the definition are either "dependent" names or "non-dependent" names.  Non-dependent names *must* match something previously declared before the point of the template definition.  Dependent names are not looked up until the template arguments are known for a specific instantiation.  This is called "two-phase lookup".

In your example, `test();` has nothing to make `test` dependent, so it is non-dependent and looked up immediately.  The `test` in `Base<T>` can't be found since a specialization of `Base` might not have a member `test`, or might declare it entirely differently.

You can make `test` a dependent name by writing `this->test();` or `Base<T>::test();` instead, and then the example will compile.

Comment: I wrote [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e7049a48baefba2) as you advised. So, the functions within a class template are being instantiated only when they're used, aren't they?

Comment: That's generally correct, yes.  The catch is that non-dependent semantic checks apply even if the template is never instantiated.